# Proofing implication

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

I am asked to prove if a and b are positive, then $a^2(b+1) + b^2(a+1)  \geq 4ab$

This makes me really confused. I don't know where I can start the proof. Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

The statement is not true for **all** positive $a,b$, for example $a=b=\frac{1}{2}$.  It is true for positive **integers**.  You can prove it by noting that in this case $a^2b\ge ab$ and proving that $a^2+b^2\ge2ab$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume the hypothesis to be true. That is, assume both $a$ and $b$ are positive. Now,

$$a^{2}(b+1)+b^{2}(a+1)\geq 4ab$$

$$a^{2}b+a^{2}+b^{2}a+b^{2}-2ab-2ab\geq 0$$

$$(a^{2}b+b^{2}a-2ab)+(a^{2}-2ab+b^{2})\geq 0$$

$$(a^{2}b+b^{2}a-2ab)+(a-b)^{2}\geq(a^{2}b+b^{2}a-2ab)\geq 0$$

$$\Rightarrow (a^{2}b+b^{2}a-2ab)=ab(b+a-2)\geq 0$$

Which is of course true, because $a$ and $b$ are positive natural numbers. So the equality will hold iff $a=b=1$.

Comment: I personally don't think this proof would work, as you assume the conclusion, which is in this case $a^2(b+1)+b^2(a+1)>=4ab$ to be true.

Comment: @Aaron: Ops, I forget to write my assumption. I was doing a direct proof. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

let $a,b \in \mathbb{N^*}$

$$
a^2(b+1) + b^2(a+1) \geq 4ab \iff\\
\iff (a-b)^2+(a+b-2)ab \geq 0
$$

if $a+b \geq 2$ the statement is easily seen to be true.
so it remains to prove it's validity for $a+b<2$, since $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ we only need to verify the following cases:
 1. $\ \ \ a=0 \wedge b=1$
 2. $\ \ \ a=1 \wedge b=0$
 3. $\ \ \ a=0 \wedge b=0$
the statement is true in all 3 cases.
so the relation holds true $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{N}$